# How check if Subject is no null?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7

I have the following code:

```
@Injectable()
export class FilterRegister {
  public registerFilter: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  public registerFilterParameters: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  getFilter(): Observable<any> {
    return this.registerFilter.asObservable();
  }

  getParameters(): Observable<any> {
    return this.registerFilterParameters.asObservable();
  }
}
```

How check in template if `registerFilter` is not null? Like:

```
<div *ngIf="!!registerFilter"></div>
```

Comment: `registerFilter` is assigned an initial value and I do not see any place in the code that changes that assignment. In short, why would it ever be null? Also what is wrong with what you have there (the truethy check)? Is it not working as expected?

Comment: For any kind of observable `async` pipe may be used

Comment: Could you share sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `registerFilter` is observable you need to use `async` pipe or using `subscribe`

either

```
registerFilter$: Observable<any>

this.registerFilter$ = service.getFilter();

<div *ngIf="(registerFilter$ | async)"></div>
```

or

```
registerFilter : any;

service.getFilter().Subscribe((value) => this.registerFilter = value);

<div *ngIf="registerFilter"></div>
```

### Suggestion

As a side note this will be more clean implementation of your service.

```
export class FilterRegister {
  registerFilter$ : Observable<any> = this.registerFilter.asObservable();
  registerFilterParameters$ : Observable<any> = this.registerFilterParameters.asObservable();
  private registerFilter: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  private registerFilterParameters: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  foo() {
    this.registerFilter.next('value');
  }
}
```